# why the jquery validation framework not getting called with dynamic form?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ughCm/102/

why the jquery validation framework not getting called with dynamic form??

On click of the plus  text  , i am creating a form dynamically , but the jquery validation framework is not getting called on this field

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '#forT2', function(event) {
  var html = '<div class="col9 pull-left">\
                    <form id="newcategoryformnott1" name="newcategoryformnott1">\
                    <input type="text" id="categorynotT1" name="categorynotT1" required   class="m-wrap span12" placeholder=""/>\
                     </div>\
                     <div class="col1 pull-right">\
                     <button type="submit" id="savenewcategoryforT2" class="btn default">Save</button>\
                     </div>\
                     </form>\
                        </div>';
  $("#saveandtextnotT1div").append(html);
});
$(document).on('click', '#savenewcategoryforT2', function(event) {
  $('#newcategoryformnott1').validate();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newcategoryformnott1').validate({
    rules: {
      categorynotT1: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 25
      }
    },
    messages: {
      categorynotT1: {
        required: "category Name required"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
      if ($("#newcategoryformnott1").valid()) {
        alert('haii');
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('nvalid');
        validator.focusInvalid();
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

could you please let me know how to resolve this , thanks in advance .

Comment: happy to help you . check my updated answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for  newcategoryformnott1 is not available in dom when document load. to assing validation to  newcategoryformnott1 form. use below code

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/ughCm/104/)

create function for validation and call when form append in DOM

```
 function validteform(){
    $('#newcategoryformnott1').validate({
        rules: {
           categorynotT1: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 3,
           maxlength: 25
         }
      },
         messages: {
           categorynotT1: {
           required: "category Name required"
         }
      },
      submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
        if ($("#newcategoryformnott1").valid()) {
         alert('haii');
         return false;
        } else {
         alert('nvalid');
       validator.focusInvalid();
       return true;
      }
     }
   });    
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

     $(document).on('click', '#forT2', function(event) {
      var html = '<div class="col9 pull-left">\
                <form id="newcategoryformnott1" name="newcategoryformnott1">\
                <input type="text" id="categorynotT1" name="categorynotT1" required   class="m-wrap span12" placeholder=""/>\
                 </div>\
                 <div class="col1 pull-right">\
                 <button type="submit" id="savenewcategoryforT2" class="btn default">Save</button>\
                 </div>\
                 </form>\
                    </div>';

        $("#saveandtextnotT1div").append(html);
        validteform(); // call function here 

  });

   $(document).on('click', '#savenewcategoryforT2', function(event) {
     $('#newcategoryformnott1').submit();
   }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#newcategoryformnott1')` does not exist on on dom ready this is an empty selection

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newcategoryformnott1').validate(.....
```

Bind the validation after you create it in the click handler